# Orthogonal vector space (orthogonal signal sets)

Tags: calculus, geometry, orthogonality, signal-processing

So there are three vectors: $x_1, x_2, x_3$ (which I guess have infinite length?)

on all three axises, respectively

Here are the relevant pages from the textbook: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGv6D.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWWLn.jpg)

And the tl;dr is that, I have issue with the wording on the text that implies that "g" vector is orthogonal to all three $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$ vectors.

Which is not the case!

See the picture:

[image]

There's no way angle 1, between g and $c_3 x_3$ is 90°, same with angle 2

am I misunderstanding? It's just the text said:

Completeness here means that it is impossible in this space to find **any other vector** $x_4$, **which is orthogonal** to all three vectors $x_1, x_2, x_3$.

Which implies that g is orthogonal to $x_1, x_2, x_3$

Comment: I don't see where the text implies that $\mathbf g$ is orthogonal to anything whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textbook states that the three orthogonal vectors are components of *g*. This implies that a linear combination of these basis vectors is equal to *g*. Three orthogonal vectors in 3D space span all of 3D space, therefore *g* cannot be orthogonal to the basis vectors.

Comment: how do they span all of 3d space? They only span the axises, no?

Comment: @Jack Spanning means that any 3-D vector can be represented as a linear combination of these basis vectors.